# Difference between SizedBox and Padding,Margin

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Should we use Marging,Padding or SizedBox to give spacing between widgets the Widgets the Margin and padding does the Work, so then whats the use of SizedBox

Answer (score 2):

SizedBox creates space between widget to widget only just height and width.
On the other hand, Margin is an element’s personal space — how much distance the element wants to keep with other elements around it.
Padding is how much an element is away from itself — how much distance an element wants to keep with the elements inside it.
They create distance top, bottom, left, and right.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for Responding and Explaining it  so Beautifully :)

Comment: I dont get this, whats the difference when we write `margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),` vs `SizedBox(height: 10.0)`. Both fulfiles the same purpose

Answer (score 0):

There are widgets that require a specific size so that they can be drawn, such as the GoogleMaps widget since the Height and Width must be defined, for this we can simply use a Container but more specifically the SizedBox widget helps us in this, although it is to everyone's taste